# A question about Axiomatic Set Theory: Axiom on $\in$ relation

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am exploring Axiomatic set theory out of curiosity, and was referring to https://youtu.be/AAJB9l-HAZs as an introduction to the subject. My question is here (time in video 10:47) :-

The first axiom of the theory is stated as this: **Axiom on $\in$-relation:** $x \ \in\ y$ is a proposition if and only if x and y are sets.

This does not seem like an axiom that is in an **axiomatic system**. An axiom in an axiomatic system is a formula that is not a tautology in that logic system, but is assumed to be a universal truth (Please correct me if I am incorrect). To me, this "axiom" seems to just be saying this - $\in$ is a (binary) predicate. The variables on which the truth value of $\in$ depends are called sets.

If I remember correctly, there exist some formulas in predicate logic which can neither be proved/disproved in the logic. Perhaps the professor wants to say that the only if the formulas can be proved/disproved, the variables are sets? He goes on to 'provide an application of this axiom' by showing how Russel's paradox is avoided. To me, it simply seems like he demonstrates how the formula: $\exists u ((\forall z(z \in u \iff \lnot z \in z)))$ can neither be proved nor disproved using predicate logic. (I may be extremely wrong here). Since it can neither be proved nor disproved, $u$ is not a set?

Another thing is the formal formula of the axiom which is stated:
$\forall x \forall y \ ((x \in y) \oplus \lnot (x \in y))$ - I think that this is simply a tautology? Why is this an axiom?

Comment: There are drastically different treatments of logics out there. In some of them logical axioms mix with other axioms; in some, equality is not a predicate but a logical symbol. Do not expect the treatment from one source can be carried to other places.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding this lecture series; it has quite a few errors (which I know only because people have come to this site confused by them in the past!).  That's what you get if you try to learn logic from a physicist, I guess...

Comment: `\in`, not `\epsilon`. Compre $x\in y$ with $x\epsilon y$.

Comment: @EricWofsey... Okay. But am I correct in saying that  ∃u((∀z(z∈u⟺¬z∈z))) can neither be proved/disproved in predicate logic? Or is it better to say that this proposition can not be assigned a truth value?

Comment: @Trebor. I would appreciate your thoughts on the previous comment as well :)

Comment: @SuraajKS It can be disproved: If such a $u$ exists, either $u\in u$ or $u\notin u,$ but either choice leads to a contradiction. (And we used no set theory axioms here.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So the formula is an absurdity (always false)?

Comment: @SuraajKS Yes (and again note that we could replace $\in$ with some other relation symbol, or with equality and it would still be disprovable/absurd). The point is that this statement is an instance of "naive comprehension", which asserts for any formula $\phi,$ $\exists u \;\forall x (x\in u\leftrightarrow \phi(x))$, so naive comprehension is inconsistent and needs to be replaced with something else (namely restricted comprehension, also known as separation, if we're doing ZF-style set theory).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah.. I think I understand a bit now, the set theory before ZF set theory was this "naive comprehension", which had ∃u∀x(x∈u↔ϕ(x)) as an axiom. But the system was inconsistent, and therefore, you could prove anything as true with it. Is this correct?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The $\in$ symbol originated from $\epsilon$. So I guess it is acceptable in some old formulations.

Comment: @SuraajKS Yes, that's correct. (The historical aspect might be a bit oversimplified, but it's not entirely inaccurate, and more to the point, this is the modern story we tell to motivate separation. "Here's an axiom scheme: it looks true and like a correct description of how we reason about sets, but it's fatally flawed... so here's a modified version that works.")

Comment: @Trebor: Yes, but MathJax and LaTeX treat the $\in$ symbol like a relational symbol, providing appropriate alignment and spacing, whereas $\epsilon$ is treated like a simple symbol; so there's no spacing, no alignment, etc.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, it is common practice to use $xRy$ as a relation. Why not $x\epsilon y$?

Comment: @Trebor: If you truly cannot see the typographical differences between the two, and just how legibly inferior the use of $\epsilon$ is, both for "is an element of" and even compared to the use of $R$ for a relation, then there is clearly nothing anyone could say to you to make a difference.  And you'll find very few people who use $R$ if the variables are capital latin letters. Ever seen "$ARB$" as "$A$ is related to $B$"? I haven't from anyone who actually cares about not causing needless confusion.

Comment: You are right: the purported Axiom on ∈-relation is not an axiom of the theory but a rule of the language that specifies that the language has only one binary predicate symbol: $\in$.

Comment: Also your second concern is right: LEM is a law of classical logic: $p \lor \lnot p$. Applied to a binary predicate $R(x,y)$ whatever we get: $R(x,y) \lor \lnot R(x,y)$, from which the "set version": $\in(x,y) \lor \lnot \in(x,y)$.